# Find and Replace a substring which has current focus

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to update a substring in textarea. Basically, its a twitter like @username feature. User will type in @user and I have to replace "@user.." with user's selected username.

String:

> Hello this is test@gmail.com and @gma

In above string, the focus is at the end of string i., after @gma.
I would like to replace @gma with my choice of substring. Somehow, I am not able to do it.
When I use

```
this.value = this.value.replace("@gma"+"", "ReplaceText") + ' ';
```

the @gma of the test@gmail.com is replaced. How do I change the recently typed @gma?

I can get the caret position, but not able to replace the required substring.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you consider the reverse approach? Looking for all words in the text that start with @ then matching the string in a hash table to get the replacement?  Seems to me this would both solve your problem and be more efficient because you only move though the text once and adding more replacement texts would be easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use RegEx instead of a normal string for the replacement.

```
this.value = this.value.replace(new RegExp("@gma$","g"), "ReplaceText") + ' ';
```

The important part is the `$` sign, which means to search for `@gma` only at the end of the string. If you want to replace any alphanumeric string after the last `@` sign:

```
this.value = this.value.replace(
    new RegExp("@[A-Za-z0-9]+$","g"), 
    "ReplaceText") 
+ ' ';
```

Comment: Seems a little too similar to mine for coincidence after your edit.

Comment: I reread the question and realized that @gma wasn't the only string he needed to capture. There's only so many ways to represent an alphanumeric character range in Regex. :P

Answer (score 1):

If you know the username is always going to be at the end of the string, you can use the regex end of string match `$`:

```
value = "Hello this is test@gmail.com and @gma";
var re = new RegExp("@[a-zA-Z_0-9]+$");
value = value.replace(re, 'Replace Text');
console.log(value);
// => "Hello this is test@gmail.com and Replace Text"
```

Twitter usernames are allowed allowed to contain letters, numbers and underscores.